# What is a good example of stripe payments built on top of node.js?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to find a good example of stripe payments integrated into node.js server. Stripe documentation has good examples of php, python, and ruby and there are great example full function apps in these languages, but not much in Javascript and integrating with the node-stripe npm module. I found [this](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/stripe-payments-with-node/) well visited example really helpful.

Anyone find or would like to share any other examples of node.js implementation of stripe payments?